# VBScript: Create object throws error

Tags: vbscript

Below are the cases i tried to create object of instance "COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection".
But I`m getting error saying:

```
   "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: ActiveX component can't create object: 'COMAdminCatalogCollection'"
```

Code:

```
dim aa,bb,cc
set aa = new ActiveXObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection")
'Set bb =  Createobject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection")
'set cc =   Createobject("COMAdminCatalogCollection")
```

I dont have any idea about the instance "COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalogCollection", I tried to find dlls to register to fix the issue I got nothing on internet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get Collection from COMAdminCatalog

```
Set objCatalog = CreateObject("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog")
Set oTSCol = objCatalog.GetCollection("TransientSubscriptions")
Set objCatalog = nothing
```